# Refactor React UseEffect removing repeating else if

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, refactoring, use-effect

I have the following `useEffect`

I want to refactor it, removing all these `else if` lines

See the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(country === "WW") {
        setIsDisable(true);
    } else if (country === "GB") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "DE") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "FR") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "BR") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "US") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "IT") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "US") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "ES") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    } else if (country === "MX") {
        setIsDisable(false);
    }
  }, [country]);
```

As you can see the country: `GB`, `DE`, `FR`, `BR`, `US`, `IT`, `US`, `ES` and `MX` sharing the same `setIsDisable(false)`

How would you write in 1 line of code whitout repeating the same `else if` ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if none of them matches? Right now, you don't do anything.

Comment: If the country is guaranteed to be one of these, all you need is `setIsDisable(country === "WW")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => {
   setIsDisable(country === "WW");
}, [country]);
```

if you want to validate

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (country === "WW")
      setIsDisable(true);
   else if (["GB", "DE", "FR", "BR", "US", "IT", "ES", "MX"].includes(country))
      setIsDisable(false);
}, [country]);
```